# Using Google Computing Services

Tags: google-cloud-platform, multiple-instances

I am using google computing services and created an instance which I accidentally deleted. Is there anyway to recover the VM instance?

Thank you very much

Comment: Unless you backed up the VPS I very much doubt you can do anything. Have you tried contacting Google Computing Services Support?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible.

See the Google Cloud Platform FAQ here:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/faq#caniretrieve